# Getting errors when I am trying to run the hellogridview

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am getting some errors when I am trying to run the hellogridview from the Android website.

**GridView.java**

package com.GridView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

```
public class GridView extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()) {
            public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > parent, View v,int position, long id){
                Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

error with this statement
`(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview)`
error with
`setAdapter()`
error with
`OnItemClickListener()`
error with
`AdapterView<?>`
error with
`HelloGridView`
error with
 });

all this was copied from the [android website.](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)

**Image Adapter.java**

```
package com.GridView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView1(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
```

Comment: Can you post your layout xml file?

Comment: yes it will be in the main post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i noticed you have not imported the Android GridView class and the AdapterView class. Add the following imports to your GridView.java:

```
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
```

Comment: here are the imports i have for the HelloGridView.java. import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

Comment: here are the imports i have for ImageAdapter.java.import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

Comment: also, please make sure that when you create a new OnItemClickListener(), declare it as new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()

Comment: where are you talking about in the code? I just copied and pasted from the google site

Comment: i am talking about here : gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()) . the google site code doesnt work properly.

Comment: The method OnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type AdapterView. this is the error i got when i changed it

Comment: have you tried this: gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()   instead of the original code which was  gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()?

Comment: that fixed that error im now getting an error with this statement,  gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

Comment: is ImageAdapter in the same package as your GridView class?

Comment: p.s. could you also please up-vote the individual comments which have helped you so far? thanks

Comment: are you given any extra information about the error? i.e. what the error could be?

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler is getting very confused. You have named your class GridView, but you should naming it HelloGridView according to the example. GridView is a class beloning to the Android API. I recommend deleting the project and starting again following the instructions exactly, since otherwise you will need to change a few other things manually to make the app work again. Since their example also misses out all of the required import lines, you must add these yourself. You can do this by pressing ctrl+shift+o in Eclipse.

Comment: still getting an error on (in the HelloGridView.java) 
(new ImageAdapter(this))  ,
setOnItemClickListener  ,
OnItemClickListener  ,

Comment: Did you add the ImageAdapter class to your project again? Is it in the same package?

Comment: in the ImageAdapter I'm getting errors with the samples mThumbIds = {
R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
it is giving me an error for the samples only

Comment: the tree is a follows
src,
com.HelloGridView,
HelloGridView.java,
ImageAdapter.java

Comment: You need to have valid pictures (typically .png files) in one of your drawable folders with those names. Use the samples given to you in the zip file in step 2. of that tutorial, unzip them, and save all the files in the res/drawable folder of your project. You will probably need to make that folder, make sure you spell it correctly.

Comment: i have 3 drawable files  
res/drawable-hdpi, res/drawable-idpi, and res/drawable-mdpi. the pictures are currently in the first folder

Comment: Yes, make a new folder that is just /drawable without any -mdpi etc.   Put the pictures directly into that new folder. Don't leave them in the zip file or the sample_images folder they came in.

Comment: they arnt they are extracted i copied and pasted them there